# How to use regexp with find in -name and -path?

Tags: regex, bash, find

I have a main folder that contains files and subfolders and I want to move all the graphic files (`pdf`, `png`, `jpg`, and so on) in a new folder callded `figs` (inside my main folder).

I want to exclude:

- all the subfolders whose name starts with `Copy_of_`
- all the folders whose name contains `copy 1` and `tikz`
- all the `pdf` files whose name starts with `Copy_of_`, `XXX`, `YYY`, `ZZZ`

I wrote this code:

```
# not pdf
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*(jbig2|jpeg|jp2|jpg|jpx|png)$' ! -path '*/Copy_of_*/*' ! -path '*/*copia 1*/*' ! -path '*/tikz*/*' ! -path 'figs' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} "figs"

# pdf
find . -type f \( -name "*.pdf" ! -name "Copy_of_*" ! -name "XXX*" ! -name "YYY*"  ! -name "ZZZ*" \) ! -path '*/Copy_of_*/*' ! -path '*/*copy 1*/*' ! -path '*/tikz*/*' ! -path 'figs' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} "figs"
```

I split my code into two parts because I can't manage it in one solution.

Is there a way to do it all with one call to `find` and/or to use regular expressions for `-name` and `-path` thus avoiding having to specify them one by one?

Comment: Add `-i` to `mv` to avoid "clobbering" files, if more than one target file has the same name.

Comment: @daveloyall Thanks. There is another part of my code that deals with files that have the same name, but which are stored in separate folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot of complex things when you go to town with grouping expressions (as you already did in your first `find` command, along with `-and` and `-or`).  Check out the `OPERATORS` section of its man-page.

Something like this, for instance:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

find \
     . -type f \
     ! -path '*/Copy_of_*/*' \
     ! -path '*/*copia 1*/*' \
     ! -path '*/tikz*/*' \
     ! -path 'figs' \
     \( \( -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*(jbig2|jpeg|jp2|jpg|jpx|png)$' \) -or  \
        \( -name "*.pdf" ! -name "Copy_of_*" ! -name "XXX*" ! -name "YYY*"  ! -name "ZZZ*" \) \) \
     -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -I {} echo {}
```

This test snippet merely `echo`s the files that it thinks it should move. For a quick test I created some (empty) files:

```
$ tree
.
|-- Copy_of_figs
|   `-- 1.jpg
|-- Copy_of_pdf_1.pdf
|-- Hello
|   |-- 1.jpg
|   |-- 2.png
|   `-- 3.pdf
|-- figs
|-- snippet.sh
`-- tikz
    `-- 4.pdf

4 directories, 7 files
```

Where this was the result:

```
$ ./snippet.sh
./Hello/2.png
./Hello/1.jpg
./Hello/3.pdf
```

Sidenote: You refer to `copia 1` in one `find` statement and to `copy 1` in another. Don't know if the former was a typo, or if both patterns needed to be excluded.

Comment: Erwin Yes, it's a typo. It seems to me that you are indirectly confirming that it is not allowed to use regexp with `name` and `path`, isn't it?

Comment: The `-name` and `-path` options don't work with regex patterns, no, but `-regex` and `-iregex` are the "regex versions" of `-path` and `-ipath`, respectively, as far as I can tell.